# How to search and replace this line in the text. c# regex

Tags: c#, regex

How to found and replace what is in a quotes in the string?

String for search and replace is

```
#define IP "127.0.0.1"
```

First I read all text from the file

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Than how to replace the what is in a quotes in the string?

Thanks.

Comment: By what do you want the text to be replaced?

Comment: Do you want to replace all occurences of "127.0.0.1" in the whole file by `whateverstring`? What is if file contains `localhost` instead of that given string?

Comment: I need to replace what is in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1(v=vs.110).aspx). Example:

```
 var input = "#define IP \"127.0.0.1\"";
 var replacement = "4.4.4.4";

 Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}");
 string result = rgx.Replace(input, replacement);

 // result: #define IP "4.4.4.4"
```

The regular expression `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` will match any IP. I've created an [example on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JsJFuk) for you to see it matching 3 different IP Addresses.

Comment: But how found this string in the document?

#define IP "{pattern}"

Comment: @JingoBingo See edit, I've changed the example in and shown you the out.

Comment: Yes.. But if I don't know what would be in " "?
127.0.0.1. It's just an example.